# Robolectric 2.0 not creating views when testing

Tags: robolectric, roboguice

I'm trying to set up testing with robolectric and roboguice. I'm successfully injecting and testing classes but when i try to test activities i can't seem to create View objects in the test environment

I get the following errors

> testAttemptsLoginWhenSignInButtonIsClicked(com.clearc2.HomeActivityTest)
>   Time elapsed: 2.234 sec  <<< ERROR! java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed
>   to create a android.widget.EditText   at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.constructView(LayoutBuilder.java:182)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.create(LayoutBuilder.java:109)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.doInflate(LayoutBuilder.java:42)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.doInflate(LayoutBuilder.java:45)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.doInflate(LayoutBuilder.java:45)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.doInflate(LayoutBuilder.java:45)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.inflateView(LayoutBuilder.java:62)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLayoutInflater.inflate(ShadowLayoutInflater.java:50)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLayoutInflater.inflate(ShadowLayoutInflater.java:55)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)     at
>   org.robolectric.tester.android.view.RoboWindow.setContentView(RoboWindow.java:80)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.setContentView(ShadowActivity.java:265)
>     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)   at
>   com.clearc2.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:38)   at
>   com.clearc2.HomeActivityTest.setUp(HomeActivityTest.java:22)  at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:246)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)  at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:181)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)    at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:103)
>     at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:169)    at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.constructView(LayoutBuilder.java:167)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.create(LayoutBuilder.java:109)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.doInflate(LayoutBuilder.java:42)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.doInflate(LayoutBuilder.java:45)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.doInflate(LayoutBuilder.java:45)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.doInflate(LayoutBuilder.java:45)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.inflateView(LayoutBuilder.java:62)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLayoutInflater.inflate(ShadowLayoutInflater.java:50)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLayoutInflater.inflate(ShadowLayoutInflater.java:55)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler$ShadowMethodPlan.run(ShadowWrangler.java:440)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)     at
>   org.robolectric.tester.android.view.RoboWindow.setContentView(RoboWindow.java:80)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.setContentView(ShadowActivity.java:265)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler$ShadowMethodPlan.run(ShadowWrangler.java:440)
>     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)   at
>   com.clearc2.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:38)   at
>   com.clearc2.HomeActivityTest.setUp(HomeActivityTest.java:22)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:246)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)  at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:181)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)    at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:103)
>     at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:169)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     ... 2 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "@0"    at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)     at
>   com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:123)
>     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)   at
>   android.widget.TextView.**constructor**(TextView.java:827)    at
>   android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:447)     at
>   android.widget.EditText.(EditText.java:60)  at
>   android.widget.EditText.(EditText.java:56)  at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.constructView(LayoutBuilder.java:167)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.create(LayoutBuilder.java:109)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.doInflate(LayoutBuilder.java:42)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.doInflate(LayoutBuilder.java:45)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.doInflate(LayoutBuilder.java:45)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.doInflate(LayoutBuilder.java:45)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.res.builder.LayoutBuilder.inflateView(LayoutBuilder.java:62)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLayoutInflater.inflate(ShadowLayoutInflater.java:50)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLayoutInflater.inflate(ShadowLayoutInflater.java:55)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)     at
>   org.robolectric.tester.android.view.RoboWindow.setContentView(RoboWindow.java:80)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.setContentView(ShadowActivity.java:265)
>     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)   at
>   com.clearc2.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:38)   at
>   com.clearc2.HomeActivityTest.setUp(HomeActivityTest.java:22)  at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:246)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)  at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:181)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)    at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:103)
>     at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:169)    ... 2
>   more

Answer (score 6):

found the problem. Robolectric didn't like the android ime options set on my password EditText. As soon as i removed those lines the test ran as expected.

Comment: This is the right answer and it was a big help for me. So thanks. And don't forget to mark it as the correct answer as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar errors, but the issue was `imeActionId`, not `imeOptions`. Removing the `imeActionId` from the XML and setting it in code (but keeping the `imeOptions`) solved this problem.

Here were my errors for reference and for search engine crawlers so people can find this answer easier:

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file app/build/intermediates/res/debug/layout/fragment_registration_form.xml 
line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class com.company.project.widgets.MyCustomEditTextView
...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "@0"
...
```

I guess Robolectric cannot parse the imeActionId correctly for some reason. Looks like it's related to the issue described in this question: [Why does setting imeActionId with a predefined ID resource create an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713604/why-does-setting-imeactionid-with-a-predefined-id-resource-create-an-error/23740834#23740834)