# android:ime Rendering Problems

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, ime

I have an error with Google's Login template. I use the login activity, but I always get the following error in the rendering/design screen:

```
The following classes could not be found:
- EditText (Fix Build Path)
Tip: Try to build the project.
```

The problem is caused by the android:imeActionId xml-methods. Here is my (Google's) code:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />
```

If I remove all android:ime[...] lines, its rendering perfectly fine.
I use Android Studio 1.5.1 and compileSdkVersion 21

I hope you can help me to fix this issue!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to misleading name of `android:imeActionId` line.

It's initial value `"@+id/login"` indicates it's setting its own id value, but instead it's expecting you to assign one.

Please look at [Why does setting imeActionId with a predefined ID resource create an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713604/why-does-setting-imeactionid-with-a-predefined-id-resource-create-an-error?answertab=active#tab-top)

It provides a solution that worked for me.