# Why Android imeActionId in EditText - activity.xml shows error Invalid resource type?

Tags: android, android-edittext

learning Android programming I try to run this example:
      https://abhiandroid.com/programming/shared-preference

This is snippet of my EditText in activity_login.xml

```
            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

My IntelliJ IDEA is still showing an error in row:

android:imeActionId="@+id/login"

saying: Invalid resource type, expecting integer value

Naturally in LoginActivity.java is error "Can not resolve symbol login":

```
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent  keyEvent) {
        if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
            attemptLogin();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
     }
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tcc.andsharedpreferences"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
   testInstrumentationRunner
  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}
```

Can you help me? I do not understand why Android is complaining on imeActionId type, if it is supposed to create it (@+id)????

Comment: Look at this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740834/3022836](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740834/3022836). It clearly explains the difference between a resource ID and imeActionId.

Answer (score 2):

You can define an integer value in your resources:

```
<!--res/values/integers.xml-->
<resources>
<item type="integer" name="customImeActionId" format="integer">100</item>
</resources>
```

and use it like so:

```
android:imeActionId="@integer/customImeActionId"
```

Please refers to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713604/why-does-setting-imeactionid-with-a-predefined-id-resource-create-an-error?answertab=active#tab-top) for more details